# setVisible return false when QWidget is integrated in QQuickPaintedItem

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, visible, composite

I was facing one issue with the Widget which is integrated in the QQuickPaintedItem class. When I have Widget integrated in the QQuickPaintedItem, QWidget::isVisible will return false. If I tried to set QWidget::setVisible(true) then it will open another window, which I do not want in my scenario.
Is there any way to get QWidget::isVisible return true so that my child widgets (In my actual scenario, we have 5 layer of parent child hierarchy) will also works fine when I say QWidget::show()?

I have created the scenario similar to it as below.

Header file:

```
class MyItem: public QQuickPaintedItem{
    Q_OBJECT
public:

    explicit MyItem(QQuickItem *parent = 0);
    void paint(QPainter *painter);
    ~MyItem();

    Q_INVOKABLE void initButton();

protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event );
private:
    QPushButton*   bp;
};
```

source file:

```
MyItem::MyItem(QQuickItem *parent)
    : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
{
    bp = new QPushButton("Hello");
}

MyItem::~MyItem()
{
    delete bp;
}

void MyItem::paint(QPainter *painter){
    bp->render(painter, QPoint(), QRegion(), QPushButton::DrawWindowBackground | QPushButton::DrawChildren);
}

void MyItem::mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent* event )
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << bp->isVisible();
}
```

Thanks for help in advance...!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this.

Qt do not support to embed a QWidget into a Qt Quick Item in Qt5(Qt Quick 2).

In your code, QWidget is a seperate Window, and you Qt Quick item is in it's own Window.

If you want your Qt Quick item behavior like a Button, you should use Qt Quick's Button control or write one yourself.

If you really want to embed a QWidget into Qt Quick's control tree, you can use Qt Quick 1(Qt4.7/8) instead. Check out **QGraphicsProxyWidget**'s document.